# Variance of residuals given conditional variance

Tags: time-series, self-study

I am given a linear model where the residual variable $u_t$ is **stationary** and verifies: $$E[u_t|u_{t-1},u_{t-2},...]=0$$
I also have $$\sigma^2_ t=Var(u_t|u_{t-1},u_{t-2},...)=\alpha_0+\alpha_1u^2_{t-1}$$

I am asked to determine $Var(u_t)$. I tried to use the law of total variance:

$$Var(u_t)=E[Var(u_t|u_{t-1},u_{t-2},...)]+Var(E[u_t|u_{t-1},u_{t-2},...])$$
$$=E[\alpha_0+\alpha_1u^2_{t-1}]=\alpha_0+\alpha_1E[u^2_{t-1}] $$

But I am stuck calculating $E[u^2_{t-1}]$. How should I proceed?

Comment: Hints: The property related to the conditional mean, leads to a property  for the unconditional mean. Also, stationarity (I guess you mean second-order such), implies that the second unconditional moment about the mean is constant along $t$. Write the fundamental expression for the variance and combine.

Comment: So $Var(u_t)=\alpha_0 / (1-\alpha_1)$. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is correct. Glad I could be of help.